# Extract substring from this string inside Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substring, excel-2013

I have this Excel cell `A2` with the contents `USD.EUR[IDEALPRO,CASH,EUR]`.

I would like to extract the substring `EUR` from the last part of the string using an Excel formula. The nearest formula I came out with is `=RIGHT(A2,4)`. However, it returns `EUR]`.

What formula can be used to extract the substring?

I am using MS Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string that you are searching is only `3 bytes` in length, then your simple formula works. But what if it changes? Try the below,

`=MID(SUBSTITUTE(F2,",","#",LEN(F2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F2,",",""))),FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(F2,",","#",LEN(F2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F2,",",""))))+1,FIND("]",SUBSTITUTE(F2,",","#",LEN(F2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F2,",",""))))-FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(F2,",","#",LEN(F2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F2,",",""))))-1)`

Where `F2` is your string. This formula unstrings the string between the last delimiter `","` and `"]"`. This is too complicated but it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question. It has been tested to work.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,4),"]","")
```

`RIGHT(A2,4)` returns `EUR]`. Afterwards, use `SUBSTITUTE` to remove `]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `MID` and `REVERSETEXT` functions.

**Formula**

```
=REVERSETEXT(MID(REVERSETEXT(A1), 2, 3))
```

Otherwise, if the length is unknown for the part which you want to retrieve. Then use `FIND` function to find the comma before that particular word.

```
=REVERSETEXT(MID(REVERSETEXT(A3), 2, FIND(",", REVERSETEXT(A3)) - 2))
```

Comment: ReverseText() does not seem to exist in excel 2013

Comment: `ReverseText()` is available for Excel 2013

Comment: Sorry, something is wrong with my Excel. I will upvote your answer.

Comment: `REVERSETEXT` is also not present in my Office 365/Excel 2016 32-bit.  Nor is it listed at Microsoft's [Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#bm18) which includes 2016, 2013 and others. Are you sure you are not using the old morefunc.xll add-in, which did have that function?