# Remove last character from first word in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to remove the last character from first word in excel.

For example I have the cell B1 with "Teas from Spain" and I need cell A1 to be "Tea from Spain".

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract substring from this string inside Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606446/extract-substring-from-this-string-inside-excel-cell)

Answer (score 4):

Use Replace:

```
=REPLACE(B1,FIND(" ",B1&" ")-1,1,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this in A1:

```
=LEFT(B1;FIND(" ";B1)-2)&MID(B1;FIND(" ";B1);999)
```

It should work like below:

[image]

Comment: OMG!!!! Yes @ScottCraner  you are right. Sometimes making translations I make fails. Thanks for this!